# How to animate to unknown height in Angular?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, css-animations, stylus

I have a code, which looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in rows" class="my">
  <img ng-src="{{row.pictureUrl}}">
  {{row.text}}
</div>
```

The current implementation looks like this (it is CSS in Stylus format), supposed to look like slide down effect:

```
$slowAnimationDuration = 100ms
.my
&.ng-animate
    transition:all
    animation-iteration-count 1
    animation-duration $slowAnimationDuration
&.ng-enter
    animation-name fadeInQuick
    animation-timing-function ease-out
&.ng-leave
    animation-name fadeOutQuick
    animation-timing-function ease-in

@keyframes fadeInQuick 
  0% 
    height 0
    opacity  0
  20%
    height calc(0.5em + 1vh + 1px)
  50%
    opacity 0.05
  100%
    height calc(1em + 2vh + 2px)
    opacity 1

@keyframes fadeOutQuick
  0%
    height calc(1em + 2vh + 2px)
    opacity 1
  100%
    height 0
    opacity 0
```

This code works, but quality of animation so far so good. 
The issue is related to the absence of animation to `height: auto` in CSS.
I'm using AngularJS 1.5 and have ngAnimate injected.
I can fix the height of the image, but I cannot change or cut the text.

How to make rows animation nicer? Is it even possible?

Update: tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17260048/669493), looks really ugly, for some time page remains empty and after content appears. Also, this squeezing effect doesn't look appealing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that most 'collapsible' elements that animate open/close, suffer the same issue.

The way they go about it, is they add two extra states that are applied for the length of the animation. ie. `.my` would become `.my.animatingIn` for `100ms`, then be changed to `.my.animatedIn`. The `animatingIn` class animates to a fixed height.. say 100px.. then the `animatedIn` class sets it to auto. This gives the illusion of the box expanding, when in fact its animating a bit.. then snapping.

Fortunately, angular has this sort of setup for `ng-animate` out-of-the-box. Using the name of the animation, and then a `-active` version.

> For example, if you have an animation named animate, during the ngRepeat enter phase, the Angular will attach the class "animate-enter" and them the class "animate-enter-active". [Docs](http://www.nganimate.org/)

As a result, you should see this working using something like

```
$slowAnimationDuration = 100ms
.my
&.ng-animate
    transition:all
    animation-iteration-count 1
    animation-duration $slowAnimationDuration
&.ng-enter
    animation-name fadeInQuick
    animation-timing-function ease-out
&.ng-enter-active
    height auto
&.ng-leave
    animation-name fadeOutQuick
    animation-timing-function ease-in
&.ng-leave-active
    height 0

@keyframes fadeInQuick 
  0% 
    height 0
    opacity  0
  20%
    height calc(0.5em + 1vh + 1px)
  50%
    opacity 0.05
  100%
    height calc(1em + 2vh + 2px)
    opacity 1

@keyframes fadeOutQuick
  0%
    height calc(1em + 2vh + 2px)
    opacity 1
  100%
    height 0
    opacity 0
```

You may also benefit from specifying the way that you want the animate to behave by updating your html to include the `ng-animate` property

```
<div ng-repeat="row in rows" class="my" ng-animate="{enter: 'animate-enter', leave: 'animate-leave'}">
  <img ng-src="{{row.pictureUrl}}">
  {{row.text}}
</div>
```

This would event let you change the current classnames to something like `animate-quick-enter` so you still retain access to the defaults

Answer (score -1):

If you know roughly what the height of the element should be, you can animate or transition `max-height` instead.

```css
div {
  max-height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: height .5s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes height {
  to {
    max-height: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asd fasdf asdf asdf asd fasd fasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I saw this trick, but I like this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/17260048/669493 more except the fact of content squeezing during animation.